# Are marginal models safer than conditional models when you have limited data?

Tags: regression

Suppose there is a school with 15 male students and 15 female students. Each student runs 100 meters and we measure the time. Next month, the students again 100 meters and we measure the time. The month after that, the  students again 100 meters and we measure the time (we have now 3 measurements for each student)

If you told someone on the street that take one student and measure the average change in time from round1 to round3 , people would say that the reliability of three measurements could include outliers (ex: clock was not working correctly, student tripped while running, etc). And the variance would also not be reliable. (conditional model)

It would be a more reliable to look at average change in time/variance for all males vs all females (conditional model)

Or even more reliable to look at average change in time/variance for all students all together (marginal model)

Therefore, it sounds obvious ... but is marginal model more reliable than conditional model because of these issues? Marginal model: more reliable, less informative . Conditional model: less reliable, more informative?

Comment: Why not mixed effects models?

Comment: but isnt  mixed effects model basically a conditional model?